# A specific compound, fuse, link, hitch etc. synonym needed

Tags: single-word-requests

I am going through a couple of thesauruses (thesaura?) looking at alternatives for words like 'link', 'join', 'hitch' to find an apropriate one for my abstract context. My problem is that 1) as always, these dictionaries are quite unhelpful in picking up the differences, and 2) as a non-native speaker, I encountered some of these words only in particular contexts, while they may be much more generic, meaning my mental association can be flawed.

Basically, what I have are 'extensions' or links, chaining things together, which exhibit the following properties:

1. Each link adds a single unit;
2. Both the nature of the connections and the chained units are important;
3. The whole compound is an entity which exists in itself, with a separate purpose, not as a collection of its components, so words like 'listing', 'point' are out;
4. It is not homonogenous, each 'link' is a distinct, recognisable section of the whole, so words like 'blend' are out.
5. There is no specific shape, or puzzle-like nature required of the connections;

Additional restrictions:

1. Words 'join' and 'catenate' are reserved;
2. Word 'link' (and probably a couple others) are too generic and thus sadly out.

To confound things more, I have two very distinct types of this kind of thing I need separate words for:

1. An extension-like thing, which is like adding another bullet point to a list: what came before is still a part of the compound, and the added unit is in no way special among those before it;
2. An annex/appendix-like thing, where what came before is 'closed off' and the unit added is clearly distinct from the previous ones. The word 'annex' actually isn't bad, but is one of those that seem to be used only in certain contexts and I fear might sound strange.

They both use essentially the same mechanism and the difference is largely in interpretation/use and not their core nature. I hope I did not overdo it in an attempt to help highlight the specifics?

Comment: I know that you are dealing with an abstract concept but are you thinking of separate but similar objects which are joined together in a chain or train? Also are you thinking of the linking pieces as being separate from the objects (perhaps in the way that links in a necklace can join mounted jewels) or are you thinking of each object as having one link at each end (as is the case with railway rolling stock)?

Comment: A link connects two units; it can't exist without them and is indivisible. Your question also made me realise that links and units exist on different levels: each unit in the chain has a distinct identity (and can exist outside chain), while what matters with links is only their type: two links of the same type between different units are indistinguishable. So, a bit like tying things with pieces of coloured tape. Splitting hairs here, as what I look for are link names only; the units where provided for context and now I think they might only confuse the issue.

Comment: Can you make a sentence where this word would appear?

Comment: What are the mechanics of the link? In order to view the linked items to I need to know the link exists and follow it it some way or is it an action that is performed once and then the items are grouped.  Is order maintained among the linked items?  In 4 you talk about each link being a section. Is it really the link that is the section or is the link just the “glue” that connects the real content together?

Comment: I’m voting to close because there are nine requirements **for us** to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word is *Bond*. It is a distinct object that brings together others into a whole. It disappears into the collection as a component but can be called out for its own structure. Its nature need not be related to what it binds together but is separate and well structured on its own. Not James Bond though. Couldn't resist.